# java sound playing in jsf page

Tags: java

```
URL url1 = new URL("http://localhost:8080/COEE/audio/underdog.wav");
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(url1.openStream());
// Create an AudioStream object from the input stream.
//    AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);         
// Use the static class member "player" from class AudioPlayer to play
// clip.
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
```

When i am playing on my local machine(Windows machine) its working fine. When running same code on Rack Space (cloud computing), where open jdk6, tomcat, ubuntu is there. I dont think we have sound drivers on cloud computing. Do we need sound drivers in cloud computing to use above code? I am using above code in jsf page. when i click the button it goes to above code and executes it.

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{popup.captchaSpeech}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.EventLoop
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:90)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)

root cause 

javax.faces.FacesException: #{popup.captchaSpeech}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.EventLoop
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:475)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:756)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)

root cause 

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.EventLoop
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:475)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:756)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)

root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.EventLoop
    org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openImpl(PulseAudioMixer.java:654)
    org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:588)
    org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.openLocal(PulseAudioMixer.java:584)
    org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer.open(PulseAudioMixer.java:579)
    org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:95)
    org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:75)
    org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioSourceDataLine.open(PulseAudioSourceDataLine.java:90)
    com.sun.media.sound.DataPusher.start(DataPusher.java:99)
    com.sun.media.sound.DataPusher.start(DataPusher.java:83)
    sun.audio.AudioDevice.startSampled(AudioDevice.java:122)
    sun.audio.AudioDevice.openChannel(AudioDevice.java:194)
    sun.audio.AudioPlayer.start(AudioPlayer.java:140)
    com.highmark.coee.managedbean.PopupBean.captchaSpeech(PopupBean.java:404)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:172)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:475)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:756)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)a
```

Comment: Just so you know, sound is played on YOUR system, not on the cloud. So there needn't be any drivers on the cloud.

Comment: Are you trying to play the audio directly in the JSF page or via an applet in the page?  How do you play it on your local machine?

Comment: does open java6 can be a problem? Even i tried Free TTS1.2 it was working fine in my local machine but not in RackSpace(Hosting Site). What does following line means Could not initialize class org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.EventLoop

Comment: onclick from jsf page i am calling a method in java class

Comment: Free TTS and java code is working fine in localmachine when i uploaded the coed in rackspace and trying to play sounds not working.

Answer (score 5):

There's a major misconception here concerning "server side" and "client side".

```
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
```

This runs sound on the machine where this piece of code is been executed. Thus, the webserver. On your local development environment, both the webbrowser and webserver runs at physically the same machine, so it *look like* as if your webbrowser is playing sound. But this is not true, it's the webserver which does that! Now, when you publish your webapplication into the cloud, it's the cloud server who is playing sound when you execute that.

You want to play sound in the webbrowser instead. You can use HTML `<embed>` or `<object>` for this. See also [this tutorial/reference](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_browsersounds.asp). Here's an extract of relevance which is modified to suit the location of your WAV file:

```
<object classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95">
    <param name="FileName" value="/COEE/audio/underdog.wav" />
</object>
```

Comment: Lol you are completely right. My answer shows the solution for his current error, but you are right he should totally rethink his approach.

Comment: Well, it *could* be applet code. Then of course the use ofa localhost URL would be the problem. But given the JSF stacktraces, you're probably right.

Comment: i am trying to put audio for my captcha. I am trying to play with java script but not successful.

Comment: Press `Ask Question` on the right top to post a new question where you purely concentrate on playing sound on click using HTML/JS. Please note that Java/JSF is completely irrelevant in the new problem since it's just the HTML/JS producer, not the sound player. I'll at least give a hint: hardcoding `http://localhost` ain't going to work as well since the user with webbrowser doesn't run the webserver at his local machine.

Comment: URL url1 = new URL("http://xy:8080/COEE/audio/underdog.wav");
     AudioStream as = new AudioStream(url1.openStream());   even placing the file in cloud space not working

Comment: As stated in the answer, you need the HTML `<embed>`/`<object>` element to get it to run in webbrowser. Java/JSF runs in webserver, produces HTML and finally HTML runs in webbrowser. You should not hardcode `localhost` in URLs in HTML since it expects a webserver on the same machine as the webbrowser. Your webpage visitors doesn't necessarily have the same webserver on their machine as you have on your own machine.

Comment: i am using following thing to do my same task <ui:repeat value="#{captcha.imageSpeechFiles}" var="cart" rendered="#{captcha.play}">
 <embed id="embdwav" src="#{cart}" autostart="true" hidden="true"  />

</ui:repeat>

Answer (score 0):

As the error message in the stack trace shows, you are missing the class org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.EventLoop. So it looks more like your deploy to the Rack Space is not complete.

Find out what JAR contains the EventLoop class from icedtea and make sure you put it somewhere on the classpath where it can be reached. This probably means packaging it in the lib folder of your WAR.

Comment: i will try this and i will get back.

Comment: I am not getting icedtea jar files? can you give me the location?

Comment: i am using following thing to do my same task <ui:repeat value="#{captcha.imageSpeechFiles}" var="cart" rendered="#{captcha.play}">
 <embed id="embdwav" src="#{cart}" autostart="true" hidden="true"  />

</ui:repeat>

Answer (score 0):

i am using following thing to do my same task

(ui:repeat value="#{captcha.imageSpeechFiles}" var="cart" rendered="#{captcha.play}">
 (embed id="embdwav" src="#{cart}" autostart="true" hidden="true"  />

(/ui:repeat>